# How to make fluidplayer responsive?

Tags: responsive, video-player

Fluidplayer documentation says one of it's features is to be responsive, [here](https://docs.fluidplayer.com/docs/overview/#features), but can't find anywhere in the docs how to do it, and from my tests, it's doesn't seem to be responsive by default.

Also can't find a way to manually resize the player on the window.resize event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it was a bug on the library that recently got fixed.

Setting the option `layoutControls.fillToContainer` to `true` keeps the player responsive to its container.

Example:

```
fluidPlayer('video-player', {
    layoutControls: {
        fillToContainer: true
    }
}
```